# What is the default administrator password?

Tags: security, windows-server-2003

Sorry if this is an overly simplistic question, but I'm a bit stuck here.

I need a Windows machine for me to do some programming for class.  Since I have my Macbook with me everywhere I go, I figured that it would be easiest to install a VM.  Since I can get a copy of Windows Server 2k3 for free via dreamspark, I thought I'd try to do that.

Here's what happened though:  I installed Windows Server (disk one).  When the system booted up, VMware automatically installed VMWare tools and prompted me to restart.  There was also a prompt to start the installation of disc 2, but I figured it would be better to restart before doing that.

When the machine came back up, I was prompted to log in as the administrator.  The problem is that I wasn't prompted to make an administrator account or password.  Is there a default password I can use?  I've tried all the obvious ones (blank, password, etc) and Googling, but I didn't come up with anything.

Comment: This is old now, but since it was just bumped... Dreamspark now has Server 2008.

Answer (score 17):

The correct password is Evaluation1. Just look in the readme file

Comment: Evaluation1 worked for me in setting up the Win2k3 image I grabbed from vmware. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You haven't put any work into modifying the system, so just start over. You'll probably spend more time trying to find a password solution than just reinstalling the OS.

As an aside, I suggest making a copy of your virtual disk after a fresh working install, so you don't have to actually install if you do want a fresh machine.

Comment: I've been playing with MS's VirtualPC and they have a "difference virtual HDD" thing that lets you leave the old VHDD alone and only store what you change. It would be smaller than a full copy.

Answer (score 9):

Free password recovery tools:

1. [Windows Password recovery](http://www.loginrecovery.com/) - Can retrieve forgotten admin and users' passwords in minutes. Safest possible option, does not write anything to hard drive.
2. [Petter Nordahl-Hagen's Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/) - A great boot CD/Floppy that can reset the local administrator's password. See [the FAQ](http://home.eunet.no/~pnordahl/ntpasswd) for more info.
3. [Openwall's John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) - Good boot floppy with cracking capabilities.
4. [EBCD – Emergency Boot CD](http://ebcd.pcministry.com/) - Bootable CD, intended for system recovery in the case of software or hardware faults.

But as others have said, you have nothing invested in this install -- easier to just blow it away and start over.

Answer (score 4):

During the Windows Server 2003 installation process you are required to enter an Administrator password. If the installation was interrupted part way through, I suggest that you just re-install it.

Answer (score 3):

you could always use ERDCommander from Microsoft to 'reset' the administrator password, it is a free program and works great.

Comment: can you pls provide a link?

Comment: http://www.google.it/search?num=10&hl=it&newwindow=1&q=erd+commander+download+site%3Amicrosoft.com

Answer (score 2):

Since you have access to the "machine", you could try cracking the password with [Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/). But really, I agree with everyone else: just reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is probably closed, but just in case anyone finds this thread in the future, I had the same problem and finally figured it out--

When you originally setup the VM before it installed, it gave you the option to customize it with a unquie username and password.  Let's take this for example:

```
username = matt
password = p@ssword
```

After the stupid VM tools installs and reboots the server, the username is Administrator, but the password was set to whatever you filled out.  In this example:

```
username = Administrator
password = p@ssword
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I found the Solution! In the main window of VMWare it has the options: Suspend, Options, Getting Started. Choose Getting Started and you have all the info. The password is given there:

```
Username:         Administrator
Password:         Evaluation1
```

Goodluck